# Creating compound class object in visual basic

Tags: vb.net, class, oop, visual-studio-2012

I am trying to create an element object for one of my mark-up languages.
How ever i am unable to interact with the object in any way.I get errors like can not access cetern variables along with the fact if i try to create a variable of that class the program dose not treat that created variable the same as the raw class.
I know the layout is done incorrectly but unsure how to get it to work. It was original all structer then al class.

```
Structure RUI_Elements
    Public Class Text
        Class location
            Friend X As Int16
            Public Y As Int16
            Public Z As Int16
        End Class
        Public mode As String
        Structure dimensions
            Shared width As Int16
            Shared height As Int16
        End Structure
        Structure region
            Shared left As Int16
            Shared right As Int16
            Shared top As Int16
            Shared bottom As Int16
        End Structure
        Structure configModes
            Shared currentMode As Byte
            Shared modes As Dictionary(Of String, Dictionary(Of String, String))
        End Structure
        Structure contentModes
            Shared currentMode As Byte
            Shared modes As Dictionary(Of String, String)
        End Structure
    End Class
End Structure
```

It say I need to replace newtext with RUI_Element.text how ever newtext is a RUI_Element.text object

```
Structure createRUIELEMENTS
    Shared Function createTEXT() As RUI_Elements.Text
        Dim newtext As RUI_Elements.Text
        newtext = New RUI_Elements.Text
        newtext.mode = ""
        newtext.location.X = 0
        newtext.location.Y = 0
        newtext.location.Z = 0
        newtext.configModes.modes = New Dictionary(Of String, Dictionary(Of String, String))
        newtext.configModes.currentMode = 0
        newtext.contentModes.modes = New Dictionary(Of String, String)
        newtext.contentModes.currentMode = 0
        Return newtext
    End Function
End Structure
```

Comment: Why is the class wrapped in a structure?

Comment: Its hard to tell what you are trying to do, but nothing is ever instanced.  `location` for instance is a class - ***not*** an object - but the parent never initializes it.  The resulting compiler errors probably led to the spamming of Shared.  Things like the `modes` dictionary should be managed (and instanced) by the things which owns it rather than pushed into it.

Comment: I am trying to create an collection of objects that represent elements in my mark-up language.The above element is a text element. which has attribute that holds location with x,y,z coordantes,dimensios which holds width and height,region which holds the space on all sides,and content/config modes which holds which mode is active and a dictanrly of all the modes that exist. I used to use structers for all layers but it not working in this i don't know why. I trying to figeur out how to define this complex variable type.